# iron router syntax: onAfterAction

Tags: meteor, iron-router

```
Router.route('/courses/:_catalog', function () {
  var courseCatalog = this.params._catalog.toUpperCase();

  Meteor.subscribe("courseCatalog", courseCatalog);

  this.render('CourseDetail', {
    to: 'content',
    data: function () {
      return Courses.findOne({catalog: courseCatalog});
    }
  });
}, {
  onAfterAction: function() {
    if (!Meteor.isClient) {
      return;
    }
    debugger
    var course = this.data(); <======
    SEO.set({
      title: "course.catalog"
    });
  }
});
```

In the above code, please look at the `debugger` statement. I want to access the data but it seems I am doing something wrong because `this.data` doesn't exist. I also tried `Courses.find().fetch()` but I only get an empty array inside `onAfterAction`. What's the right syntax and what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be inside a `this.ready()` block:

```js
  onAfterAction: function() {
    if (this.ready()) {
      var course = this.data(); 
      ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to data first. Have a look at the waitOn function to do this. The server only sends the documents you subscribed to, and since you didn't subscribe, `Courses.find().fetch()` returns an empty array.

Also, don't put SEO stuff in onAfterAction. Put it in onRun which is guaranteed to only run once.

Comment: sorry, I already subscribed to the data but left it out in the question by mistake. So this doesn't seem to be the cause of the problem.